# What was the ratio of people who were atheist prior to the French revolution or who adopted atheism as a result of the Cult of Reason?

Tags: religion, france, social-history, christianity, french-revolution

I'm interested in the way the French people reacted to the r[eligious policies during the French revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dechristianization_of_France_during_the_French_Revolution), i. e. dechristianization and establishment of the Cult of Reason. Are there any estimates what was the religious composition of the French before and after the installment of these policies?

Comment: Wasn't atheism a crime? Might be trouble finding statisitcs of people who admitted to criminal behavior.  The French version of the Monty Python "Cake or Death" skit?

Comment: Alan Kors apparently has a [two volume history of atheism in France](https://www.amazon.com/Atheism-France-1650-1729-Disbelief-Princeton/dp/0691609063).

Comment: @BrianZ: Just the abstract alone is worth a read, as background.

Comment: Very difficult to empirically measure atheism.  Difficult to even define atheism.  Complications in definitions and measurements rise when the penalty for non-adherence is death.

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace: Then there's the difference between outright atheism (that is, believing that there isn't a god), and the various degrees of agnosticism.  As for instance you'd find a lot of people in the US who are de facto agnostics.  They'd say they were Christians if asked, but don't attend church or follow Christian religious principles.

Comment: Where to find the atheists?  Remember Cardinal Consalvi's statement to Napoleon: "If in 1,800 years we clergy have failed to destroy the Church, do you really think that you'll be able to do it?"  Atheism needn't be outward (not that Consalvi was saying the clergy were all atheists, but I'm sure he thought some of them were).